# Validity of Maxwell's equations in the aether's reference frame

Tags: physics, theoretical-physics, electromagnetism, light, maxwell

If Maxwell's equations were experimentally found on Earth such as Faradays law, coulombs law , and worked in the Earth's frame of reference, then why did people believe them to be valid in the aether's reference frame?

Comment: Maxwell equations were derived not experimentally but theoretically, in the reference frame of the aether.

Comment: Ohh,  Ok I see. The basic laws constituting Maxwells equations are experimental ex Faraday law

Comment: Not only. Maxwell went quite far in generalizing these facts:-)

Comment: Hi Dear Alexandre Eremenko, please see the question I've written it now clearly